# Export a part of sql database to import into another database

Tags: mysql, node.js

First. It's not about dump whole database.
I have a database with many project inside. One project contain many group, zone,... Some of them even many-many. 
I want to copy 1 project to another database, but it seem to impossible because primary key or foreign key between them maybe duplicate with destination database (target database is not empty). I want to copy them and keep their relation connected.

I tried JSON, but my relation table isn't hierarchical.
I can't find out how to keep them connected without save their id, but id maybe conflict with dest database. (like that id already have in dest database).

Comment: I do not get this part  `seem to impossible because primary key or foreign key between them maybe duplicate with destination database (invalid)`. Why would the copy process duplicate PKs or FKs?

Comment: @Shadow I mean. Project with id 3 have 3 group id 3,4,5. But maybe in destination dabase, already have group with id 4. Like that. It's duplicated

Comment: If I remove their key, I will lost that how they connected.

Comment: Next time you could perhaps say in the question that the target db is not empty...